# My <ul> element is outside the container

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Currently I'm making a list with images in it. It works almost, but I have one problem. My list is not placed in the container while it should be. Here's a bit of the code.

```
<div class="container">
<ul>
<li>
<div class="person1test">
  <div class="personOverlay">
  <div class="info"><span class="naam"> text </span>
  <span class="functie"> text </span></div>
 </div>
 </div></li>
<li>
<div class="person1test">
 <div class="personOverlay">
  <div class="info"><span class="naam">text </span>
   <span class="functie"> text </span></div>
  </div>
  </div></li>
<li>
<div class="person1test">
 <div class="personOverlay">
  <div class="info">
   <span class="naam"> text </span>
   <span class="functie">text</span></div>
</div>
</div></li>

</ul>
     <div class="clearer"></div>
 </div>
```

Now this is the html, you can see the "clearer"-class which I used because I floated the list elements. Here's the css.

```
.container{
height: 350px;
}

.container ul{
width: 130%;
overflow: hidden;
list-style-position: inside;
}

.container ul li{
float: left;
list-style: none;
}
```

I hope I made it clear what my problems are because English is not my main language.

Comment: I have used this code, and it seems to work fine. Do you have a JS fiddle? Or is there some missing code? (provide all css and html if you can)

Comment: i checked it is working fine

Comment: Hi, I've copied your code and saw the output. It's working fine, except the `<ul>` has width more than the container

Comment: `My <ul> element is outside the container` and if you are talking about the UI then its because `.container ul{
width: 130%;}`

Comment: Hey, this is weird. It's working on JS Fiddle. However, on my Wordpress Page , if I inspect the element, the <ul> falls out of the container, I can try to send a screenshot or something?

Comment: @Reddy Hey, now it is actually in the div.However, my .container ul is now not the width from the container class. I used the 130% to scale my <ul> so it would take the full width from the container.

Comment: doing so it will take a 130% of the container. its more than full width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Error:** This css

```
.container ul{
  width: 130%;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Will set the width of the `ul` to 130% of the container width. And that means if the container is 100px the ul will be 130px and obvously moving out of the container. Make the `ul width to be 100%` , But if the ul has some padding left or margin left set (lets say 10px) on it then since it has to be 100px wide it will go beyond the container making it look like total of 110px.

**Solution:**
So set the width to 100% and remove and padding or margin on it Or keep the margins and padding and make width to some 90% or something which will get your UI fixed.

Comment: I've set the width of the ul to 75%, and now it's in the container div again. But now I can't have all of those images where I want to. Is there a way to get all of the pictures on a line, and keeping it in the div? Here's an image what it looks like for me: [here](http://imgur.com/9EZD3Pn). The ul has a background red, the container a blue one.

Comment: you need to fix a height to your ul and say overflow hidden.

Comment: I added a height to the ul, and it already got an overflow:hidden. It didn't seem to help anything. I feel pretty dumb now because the Fiddle worked. Should I just start over and maybe it works that time? Here is another [image](http://imgur.com/DPUnWmG)

Comment: I guess your ul is geeting its style overriden. Check the inspector and find out whats happening

Comment: Hey! It actually is! There is nothing to show in the element.style tag. That might be the problem, I just have to find out what for selector I have to use now, as you can see, I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: I understand. Debug the element style in computed tab and you will see all the styles being applied on it

Comment: I am glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

You should set Height of your `<div class="container">` equals to auto. It'll solve your problem.